# How to implement WPF DataVirtualization with data coming from a database?

Tags: wpf, data-virtualization

I have an application which is connected to a WCF service collecting data from an SQL server database store procedure. From the UI side i have read many article on the use of DataVirtualization in order to optimized displaying large amount of data.

BUt after reading quite many it is ot clear how should I implement such solution for my data coming from my database.

Do i have to call all my records once from table, and then handle the whole virtualization from UI side or does the database should already return PAged records ?

I will be glad if some of you have sample implementation with SQl data and Virtualization on UI side or good link which shows that.

For time beeing I have see sample project with sample collection demo, but nothing against database stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Data virtualization and UI virtualization are different concepts. Out of the box, WPF does not offer data virtualization but it does offer UI virtualization.

The fact that your data is coming from a database is irrelevant with regard to data virtualization within the client. It could be coming from a WCF service, a database, an XML file, etc... that is irrelevant. The caching mechanisms you leverage within the database and other performance oriented items do matter but that is outside the scope of data virtualiztion.

If what you are after is indeed data virtualization within the client, check out [Bea's blog post](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344) on the topic which has a couple of solutions as well as a great explanation.

Comment: Yes I am talking of Data Virtualization. Actually my aplication is loading on start 1000 records from Database before the user can start to use data and sometimes it takes quite long. So I was thinking to optimlize this startup by fetching minimum of data in order to load the app faster and call remaining data on demand.

Comment: @user930203 Make sure you are not confusing caching at the DAL with data virtualization at the UI. You may need a combination of both based on your description.